# Jupyter notebooks: How to execute an external file containing imports and magic commands?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to have one common file containing all import and initialization magic commands (%cd, %autoreload,...). So, I would like something like this:

initialization.ipynb:

```
%cd ...
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import some_lib
import some_lib2
```

some_file.py:

```
%execute initialization.ipynb
some_lib.some_function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, I often use:

```
%run setup.ipynb
```

**Details:**

Have all your imports etc in a file named `setup.ipynb`.
Then, on top of your active notebook, insert a cell with the following content:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/yourproject')
%run setup.ipynb
```

So if you've got `setup.ipynb` stored in the `C:/yourproject` directory with the following content:

```
import os
a=1
%who
print("imports, variables and magic commands")
```

Then you'll get the following output when you run the first snippet in your active notebook:

```
a  os
imports, variables and magic commands
```

Please note that `%run` *has* to point to an `.ipynb` file if you'd like to run ipython magic commands. A regular `.py` won't work.