# How to replace jupyter-notebook magic with python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been using some jupyter notebook magics such as %matplotlib inline.

How to load them using python script instead of % signs.

## Using jupyter

```
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.displaycon=False
```

## Question: How to do the same using script?

```
# file: myimports.py
from something import x
x.load_ext('sql')
x.config('SqlMagic.displaycon',False)
```

I want to use `import * from myimports.py` in jupyter notebook, so that I don't have to type `%load_ext sql` and so many things everytime I create new jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Maybe this notebook helps your for [`matplotlib`](https://nbviewer.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb). Not sure if there exists a rule for this.

Comment: With regards to your `%matplotlib` example, what is your goal? `%matplotlib` is to set how the plotting output is handled in the notebook. If it is going to be a script run not connected to a display interface, then you don't want an equivalent for that. You may want to  have it save a figure of your plot that you can view later, e.g., `plt.savefig("my_plot.png")`. If you are going to return a plot that the notebook than can handle as previously set like the bottom of what @mosc9575 referenced, then you still don't include an equivalent because it would already be handled in the notebook.

Comment: This example [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-magics-with-sql-921370099589) shows SQL code with and without magics enabled. It would be similar to that in your script.

Comment: I want python script, so that i can import these settings from myimport.py into the notebook.  `from myimports import *`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464386/jupyter-notebooks-how-to-execute-an-external-file-containing-imports-and-magic) can help? You can create a sort of setup notebook with all needed magics and import it using %run

Answer (score 4):

You can run IPython [line magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics) using IPython `interactiveshell`:

```py
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
shell:TerminalInteractiveShell = TerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
shell.run_line_magic("load_ext","sql")
shell.run_line_magic("config","SqlMagic.displaycon=False") 
# or shell.config["SqlMagic"]={'displaycon': False}
```

> run_line_magic(magic_name, line_after_magic)

you can even run cd

```py
shell.run_line_magic("cd","..")
```

And it will work.

However, there is some magic that not working with `TerminalInteractiveShell` because it can't access your code (alias, page, ...).